# Django validate form fields manually

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a form which is dynamically generated. I cannot predict how many text inputs or multiple choices will be included before hand. Thus, I cannot use `ModelForm` or anything similar.

I wonder if I can leverage the built-in validating code from Django fields and apply them manually somehow, because I can determine the type of user inputs (e.g. whether if it is text, radio button, checkbox, etc.). Something like this would be great:

```
if type == 'Text':
    #perform validation
    #get clean data
elif type == 'Checkbox':
    #perform validation 
    #get clean data
```

---

UPDATE: My site allows users to generate a survey according to their needs. So for example, an user decides to create a survey with two questions:

1. what is your name?
2. what's the brand of your smartphone? A) iPhone B) HTC

The first question is `<input type="text">` and the second one is `<input type="radio">`

The information about what types of questions are generated is stored in the database. So I would have rows like this in the DB to describe the question:

ID TYPE TEXT
1 TEXT What is your name?
2 RADIO what is your name?

When the survey goes online and an user fills it out. I need to validate their input. How can I utilize the built-in validation functionality of Django to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you using [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), as they are here for exactly the reason you've said: dealing with the arbitrary count of fields. And that way you still will be able to use Django's validation (which is very convenient).

If you post a sample form you're dealing with, I would be able to draft a formset example.

**Update**: Ah, so you need a survey functionality? It's a totally different beast. Then I can't imagine a reason not to leverage one of the [existing solutions](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/survey-questionnaire/). The [ed-questionnaire](https://github.com/eldest-daughter/ed-questionnaire)
 package seems to be the most featured and mature one. And as always with Django, you can relatively easily customize it away.

If I haven't convinced you yet, just take a look at its [models.py](https://github.com/eldest-daughter/ed-questionnaire/blob/master/questionnaire/models.py) file. Do you really have the time and will to re-implement all that stuff?

Comment: Hi Alex, I added more description to the question.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. But what I want to accomplish is to utilize Django's validation for individual input fields without specifying any forms. I don't need existing survey packages. I just want to know that if a string get's submitted, how to validate it? Django has done it already. There mush be some package that allows you to do it.

Comment: Django's validation is done via forms. Really, the forms *are* for validation. They just take the validators for each field, run it and set errors so that you can handle it in your HTML, for example. There's no other "validation frameworks" or something in Django. If you want to clean your data, you just use forms. The problem you seem to be having is to construct a dynamic form for arbitrary number of fields. It's clearly a doable task, see https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/ for instance.

Comment: The link you provide is definitely helpful. I will see how to proceed based that information. Thanks!